# Show Pods Custom Fields Editor when a page is using a specific template in WordPress

Tags: pods-framework

I want to use pods custom fields inside a page and i would like the pods editor to appear only if the page is using a specific page template, for exemple if the page is using my
galerie.php template

I can't find a way to do it and at this point im not sure if it's even possible.

i'm using :

- wordpress 6.2.2
- Pods 2.9
- A child theme of 2021